# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.annotation.MergedAnnotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-hateoas

i'm facing issue while working with ControllerLinkBuilder when i provide method name it throw error when i don't it run and show me result.

error seems jar issue but i tried with other versions too still same '    spring-boot-starter-hateoas' it doesn;t recognize the packages for RepresentationModel & ControllerLinkBuilderlinkTo

```
@GetMapping("/{businessclass}/lists/_generic")
public  ResponseEntity<POLineResponse>  businessClass(@PathVariable final String businessclass,
        @RequestParam String _fields, @RequestParam("company") String company) {
     logger.info("Entering into businessClass {} params{} ",businessclass, _fields);

     Page<PurchaseOrderLineDTO> page= mockFsmService.generateMockPurchaseOrderLines();

     POLineResponse polR = new POLineResponse (page.getContent(),page.getTotalElements());
     //polR.add(linkTo(LoadTestController.class).businessClass(businessclass,_fields,company)).withSelfRel();
    //polR.add(ControllerLinkBuilderlinkTo(LoadTestController.class).withSelfRel());

      Link selfLink = ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodOn(LoadTestController.class).businessClass(businessclass, _fields, company))
      .withSelfRel();

    polR.add(selfLink);
     return new ResponseEntity<>(polR, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

[refer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRGJE.png)

dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.hateoas/spring-hateoas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

maven pom

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.demo.cloudproj</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudproj-loadtest</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>cloudprojloadtest</name>
        <description>cloudprojLoadTest</description>

        <properties>
            <java.version>12</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
                <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
                <version>4.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                <artifactId> json-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>3.9</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.codearte.jfairy</groupId>
                <artifactId>jfairy</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.0</version>
            </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!--resources> <resource> <directory>src/main/resources</directory> <filtering>true</filtering> 
            <excludes> <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude> </excludes> </resource> </resources -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>false</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>

                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-antrun-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.8,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>run</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Don't do a "tag" spam and don't post an error as image, just include it as a text to the question. Do you have any parent specified in your pom? It looks like the MergedAnnotations are in the spring-core dependency, so if the spring-boot is not the parent then you'll need to include core by your self.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot why manually add depndencies? This will lead to incompatible versions of frameworks.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes you are right but when i'm adding      https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-hateoas 
it shows compile issue and the RepresentationModel and ControllerLinkBuilder showing compile time error

Comment: @M.Deinum any suggestions?

Comment: Add the one that belongs to the spring boot version you are using. The fact that you also manually add `spring-data-commons` makes me wonder what else is there. Looks like your dependencies are messy. One thing why have 3 json libraries on  your classpath?

Comment: Your pom looks incomplete in the question. Just the dependencies section should be enough.

Comment: already tried with <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

it worked but as say shows this error

Comment: You shouldn't add those dependencies. Just add the `spring-boot-starter-hateoas` WITHOUT a version all those are managed by Sprig Boot.

Comment: @M.Deinum  after doing so it shows compile error on my code on methodOn function
    Link selfLink = ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodOn(LoadTestController.class).businessClass(businessclass, _fields, company))
    .withSelfRel();

Comment: Then that method doesn't exists and you are using code samples from a different version of Spring Hateaos. Nonentheless please add the additional pom parts (currently it is broken off).

Comment: @M.Deinum just update the pom

Answer (score 2):

You should be on at least Spring Boot 2.2. With that, you can use `spring-boot-starter-hateoas` which brings in Spring HATEOAS 1.0, the version with `RepresentationModel` etc.

That version also depends upon Spring Framework 5.2, which needs to leverage `MergedAnnotations`. Using Boot 2.1 will put you on an older version of Framework, hence causing all kinds of issues.

Comment: i posted this question earlier and yes your answer is correct this was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you add below dependency again and run the application

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    <version>0.25.1.RELEASE</version> //you can add latest version or down 
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version> //you can add latest version or down 
</dependency>
```

Comment: found answer why RepresentationModel is not working 
As In case you are using HATEOAS v1.0 and above (Spring boot >= 2.2.0), do note that the classnames have changed. Notably the below classes have been renamed:

ResourceSupport changed to RepresentationModel
Resource changed to EntityModel
Resources changed to CollectionModel
PagedResources changed to PagedModel
ResourceAssembler changed to RepresentationModelAssembler

Comment: `<version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>` OR `<version>0.25.1.RELEASE</version>` You can change as you wish , I have added only and for getting idea and what kind of things it should be added